# VSFTPD 553 Could not create file. Error:Critical file transfer error

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have LAMP server with Ubuntu 18.04
i try grant access for `ftpuser` to the web folder `example.com`
her is `ls -l` output

```
dr-xr-xr-x 15 ftpuser ftpuser 4096 Jul 25 22:22 example.com
```

and here is conf file:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www

pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES

allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO

require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

I've got error:

```
Response:   553 Could not create file.
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

when i'm trying to upload file
and

```
Command:    DELE README.md
Response:   550 Delete operation failed.
```

when trying to delete one of the files in the folder
Can anybody help to deal with it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure the permission doesn't allow writing: `dr-xr-xr-x`?!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had the same issue. I have enabling passive mode, then resolved it.

vsftpd.conf

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that your ftp server is actually using the ftpuser permissions.

vsftpd.conf

```
ftp_username=ftpuser
```